# LINQ Group By Type for each user

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq, webforms

I have a list of objects with following structure

```
public class Jobs
    {
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string JobNumber { get; set; }
        public string JobPriority { get; set; }
        public string JobType { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    }
```

What I would like to do is to return a List of objects which contains

```
EmployeeName,
Total Count of Jobs assigned to him,
Job Type  & Count of each job type assigned to an emploee.
```

So in essence, I would need list of records to appear like the attached image below. I will use the result from the LINQ query and bind it to a asp.net GridView

```
Andrew
Total Jobs: 12
Build Jobs: 3
Config Jobs: 4
Delivery Jobs: 3
```

How can I achieve a result using the linq from the initial list that i have. I guess for pros, this would be a very simple and straight-forwad LINQ query.

[image]

EDIT: Added for final structure that i want:

I would like to get the result from LINQ into following structure. i.e. List of UserJob

```
public class UserJob
    {
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public int TotalJobs { get; set; }
        public List<UserJobGroup> Tickets { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserJobGroup
    {
        public string JobType { get; set; }
        public int JobCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826062/linq-group-by-type-for-each-user/35826224#35826224) already explained it. With your specific classes, it's even easier - all you need is to follow the steps he described and translate them to LINQ. You should really be able to do that yourself, especially with query syntax:

```
var result =
    (from job in jobList
     group job by job.EmployeeName into employeeNameJobs
     let jobTypeJobs =
        (from job in employeeNameJobs
         group job by job.JobType into jobTypeJobs
         select new UserJobGroup
         {
             JobType = jobTypeJobs.Key,
             JobCount = jobTypeJobs.Count()
         })
         .ToList()
     select new UserJob
     {
         EmployeeName = employeeNameJobs.Key,
         TotalJobs = jobTypeJobs.Sum(item => item.JobCount),
         Tickets = jobTypeJobs
     })
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks to @dasblinkenlight and you, I have managed to get it working...you guys are amazing...i had been scratching my head around this for more than 4 hours....Thanks a lot to both of you getting this fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Let's walk through the structure of the query that you are trying to build:

- At the top level you need groups by employee
- At the employee level you need two related, but separate, things:
- You need separate counts by job, and
- You also need the total of these counts

Now let's build the query. Start with `GroupBy` for the top level:

```
var empGroups = jobList.GroupBy(j => j.EmployeeName);
```

Convert each group to a dictionary with `EmployeeName` serving as the key, and job group counts stored as values:

```
var jobCountsByEmployee = empGroups
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key
    ,   g => g.GroupBy(j => j.JobType)
              .ToDictionary(jg => jg.Key, jg => jg.Count())
    );
```

Finally, add totals to construct the result that you want:

```
var res = jobCountsByEmployee
    .ToDictionary(
        p => p.Key
    ,   p => new {
            Total = p.Value.Sum(jc => jc.Value)
        ,   CountByJob = p.Value
        }
    );
```

Comment: Great stuff @dasblinkenlight. That actually took me one step closer to what I want. Only if you can actually help me cross that one final step. See my update in the question for more details.....I now want to move the data from your last query (var res) to collection of objects. If you can help me get that, i would mark this as answer...thanks a ton.

Comment: @user869375 Sure, I should be able to help once I get to my computer (It's no use editing code on the phone). In the meantime, you may want to try doing this as an exercise in projecting dictionaries into lists. It's a nice thing to learn, because it shows up often enough, especially in the display code.